Troubleshooting water flow from Moen kitchen faucet
This is a multipart question but it's all getting at one problem - trying to fix flow problems in our kitchen's moen faucet.  Specifically, we having two problems that started at the same time:

Reduced water flow
Water takes a few seconds to stop after turned off at handle

BACKGROUND: Last week, our house's lead service line was replaced by the city water authority (good!).  After the cutover, all of our fixtures resumed working as usual except for one faucet.  Since the other fixtures all work as expected, I think the problem is localized to this fixture.
WHAT I'VE TRIED

My first move was to clean out the aerator which had some gunk in it.  This helped with water flow but did not get all the way back to where it had been.  Removing the aerator entirely has a good flow so I'm guessing gung from the line replace ment got into the aerator internals and will try replacing it.  But this didn't help with the shut-off issue.

I wanted to pull out the cartridge to inspect, clean, and possibly replace -- but I can't figure out how to get it out, hence part two...


Can you help me identify the faucet or cartridge?
It is a moen model.  Predates our ownership of the house and I don't have a manual or even a model number.  I can't find it listed anywhere on Moen's website, BUT it is shown in a picture on this page... although when I click through to the documents linked below that picture they don't seem to match my model.

When I remove the lever, I can see the top of the cartridge but I can't figure out how to remove it from the casing or see what model the cartridge is.  Here's a picture:

Anyway... I'm stuck for the moment, but thank you for any help or advice with:

What is the faucet model?
What is the cartridge model?
How can I remove the cartridge?
How can I solve the "water doesn't stop right away when the water's disconnected" problem?

